# Communicate between two pages / tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanting a JavaScript file to control two HTML files **simultaneously**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tryAgainPage1</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="page1"></div>

  <script src="tryAgain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's page one. Next is page two.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>tryAgainPage2</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="page2"></div>

  <script src="tryAgain.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
newFunction();

function newFunction() {
    document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML = "page one says hello";
    document.getElementById("page2").innerHTML = "page two says goodbye";
}
```

Page one is working, page two isn't. I've been trying for a day to get pages talking to each other, without success. I'm not sure I understand how to implement **Broadcast channel** in this instance (if indeed that is appropriate.) Can anyone help?

Comment: `document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML = "page one says hello";` is an error on pages with no `page1` element. Errors cause the rest of the script to be aborted so that other lines don't run. Your script has nothing to do with communication between two tabs though. It's just a single script that both tabs run every time they're loaded. If you need tabs to communicate you might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your end goal is. You mention [broadcast channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) and pages "talking" to each other, but your example seems to simply be a single JS file that is intended to interact with more than one page.

Comment: My eventual goal is to use user input on one page and have it displayed on another page simultaneously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling a function or communicating from one browser window to another using Jquery / javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437088/calling-a-function-or-communicating-from-one-browser-window-to-another-using-jqu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `postMessage`

If you're looking for a way to make two **pages** or **tabs** communicate you can take a look at:
[MDN *Window.**postMessage***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), and read this [***postMessage*** article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)
or  [MDN ***Broadcast_Channel_API***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

***Using Broadcast Channel API*** **[page1](http://jsbin.com/fuqebuk/1/)** — **[page2](http://jsbin.com/vitefud/2/)**

***How it works:***

- **pageX** subscribes to a named Broadcast Channel object
- **pageY** broadcasts to the same Channel name using `postMessage`
- **pageX** listens to `"message"` events and prints the `Event.data`

And *vice-versa*.

[image: JavaScript Communicate between tabs using Broadcast Channel API]

> *page1.html*

```
<h1>PAGE 1</h1>
<p><button data-broadcast="Page 1 talking!">BROADCAST</button></p>
Page 2 says: <div id="page2"></div>
<script src="comm.js"></script>
```

> *page2.html*

```
<h1>PAGE 2</h1>
<p><button data-broadcast="Page 2! 'Allo 'Allo!">BROADCAST</button></p>
Page 1 says: <div id="page1"></div>
<script src="comm.js"></script>
```

> *comm.js*

```
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('comm');

document.querySelector("[data-broadcast]").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  bc.postMessage( ev.target.dataset.broadcast );
});

const targetEl = document.querySelectorAll("#page1, #page2");

bc.addEventListener("message", ev => {
    [...targetEl].forEach( el => el.innerHTML = ev.data );
});
```

---

## `localStorage` and the `storage` Event

Another simple, yet cool way, if both **tabs** are on the same domain is by using
[*Window.**localStorage***<sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) and its `Storage Event`.

***How it works:***

- **pageX** writes to `localstorage[pageX]`
- **pageY**'s `window` will trigger a `storage` event
- **pageY** can now read `localstorage[pageX]` or better (to make it simpler (and *pageN* agnostic)) the `Event.newValue` sent by the storage event

And *vice-versa*.

***For starters:*** DEMO: [**page1**](http://jsbin.com/hapifef/2/) — [**page2**](http://jsbin.com/yemurul/1/)

[image: JavaScript Communicate between tabs using localStorage]

> *page1.html*

```
<h1>PAGE 1</h1>
<textarea data-sender="page1" placeholder="Write to page 2"></textarea>
Page 2 says:  <div id="page2"></div>
<script src="comm.js"></script>
```

> *page2.html*

```
<h1>PAGE 2</h1>
<textarea data-sender="page2" placeholder="Write to page 1"></textarea>
Page 1 says:  <div id="page1"></div>
<script src="comm.js"></script>
```

> *comm.js*

```
// RECEIVER
window.addEventListener("storage", ev => {
    document.getElementById( ev.key ).innerHTML = ev.newValue;
});

// SENDER
[...document.querySelectorAll("[data-sender]")].forEach( el =>
    el.addEventListener("input", ev => localStorage[el.dataset.sender] = el.value )
);
```

---

## Web RTC

You could use [***Web RTC***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) (Web Real-Time Communications). *A technology which enables Web applications and sites to **capture and** optionally **stream** audio and/or video media, as well as to exchange arbitrary data between browsers*

---

#### *Your main errors:*

Your script was not working on one page... actually on **both**, the only difference was that on page 1 broke after realizing `#page2` Element could not be found - Inversely on the other page broke immediately after realizing there is no `"#page1"` Element (since first in order).
You should always check if al element exists using `if ( someElement ) { /*found!*/ }` .

And yes, you cannot make *communicate* two pages that way. They will only share / include the same JS file.

Comment: Your answer is good. However the question is about usage of [broadcast channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

Comment: @RaphaMex thx I noticed that from the OP's Q. It just took some time to expand.

Comment: How do I access the text in the data-broadcast message that is sent, as I want  to alter it's content? It won't work trying to id it and using innerHTML.

Comment: I should add that the content of the data-broadcast message will be generated from an input box by users.

Comment: @nooby simply use the `ev.data`. If you want to find out what you can access try `console.log( ev )` and explore the returned object.
Instead of buttons use `<input>`, instead of `click` use the `input` Event. You can find most of the underlying logic in the second example. Mix the two :)

Answer (score 0):

Both pages are throwing an error, the difference is, on the first page the error doesn't happen until after the div is changed.

Here's one possible approach.

```
newFunction();

function newFunction() {
  var page = document.getElementById("page1") ? "1" : "2";
  var msg = page == "1" ? "page one says hello" : "page two says goodbye";
  document.getElementById("page"+page).innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Comment: That will indeed make the single JS file work on the two different pages, but that is not the same as the two pages "talking" to each other.

Comment: You are right, but it does not answer the question. The question is about communication between 2 tabs in a same browser (hence 2 pages).

Comment: @RaphaMex that's a pretty good assumption, but it's still an assumption. despite requests for clarification OP has not shed any light on the subject.

Comment: Hi I wrested a bear. My goal is for a 'controller' page (tab one)which has controller input, which in turn sends data to a 'user page' (tab 2.).