# How to send tab data between tabs in chome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to send tab data between tabs in chome extension?

I'm trying to use onMessage. Unsuccessfully.

I still don't understand how this message is sent.

Could anyone tell how can I do?

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
          //console.log(response.farewell);
          var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
            bkg.console.log(response.farewell);
        });
      });
});
```

Receive on another tab

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(sender.tab ?
                  "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                  "from the extension");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
```

Comment: Might this be helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392467/383904

Comment: I have almost identical code in my `background.js` and content script and it works; are you sure your content script is being injected?

Comment: I want to take content from any site and send it to the site.

That is why I need to use extensions.

Comment: Anthony - 
How do you know?

Comment: what if you remove the `chrome.tabs.query` since you have a `tab` in the `browserAction.onClicked.addListener` callback and just do `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { greeting: "hello" });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        

      console.log(sender.tab ?
                  "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                  "from the extension2");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
```