# How can I change the class property of element in another page, when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have one question.
I tried to find the solution on Google, but couldn't find the best solution.
For example, one page(first) has one button, another page(second) has button and text.
at the initial status, in the second page, when i click the button, the text will be shown and hidden.
at the first, text was hidden.
and when i click the button at the first page, it goes to the second page.
in this case, i'd like to open the text when i click the button at the first page.
For this, i need to change the css property of second text element (show) using jquery.

How can i implement this?
please give me any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: When you change page you can pass arguments in the url. Read them on the next page and use them to change the css you need :)

Comment: sorry @Mick
can you attach some example such as fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [communicate-between-two-pages-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48390382/383904)

Comment: *"the text will be shown and hidden"* could you please be a little bit more precise? Add some code of what you tried. Please read [ask], take a [tour] if you missed it, [edit] and create a [mcve].